# How to set width of mat-grid-tile

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

**HTML**

```
 <mat-grid-list cols="2" [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="486px" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
   <mat-grid-tile >

   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile >

   </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

How can i give width of 30% for 1st `mat-grid-tile` 70% for 2nd `mat-grid-tile`, and how can i set the height of `mat-grid-tile` equivalent for all the devices?

Comment: are you want to set the `height` in pixels or in `%` of  total screen

Comment: please give `height` in %

Answer (score 8):

You can add `colspan`. Make sure that the sum of col span is equal to cols Size.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="2:1" >
<mat-grid-tile colspan="3">1</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile colspan="1">2</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj8zfr?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.html)

Comment: Stackblitz is broken. Attracted upvotes but not answer - Tried <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="1em">
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">4</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
But it didnt work. only css  change works
mat-grid-tile {
  background: lightblue;
  max-width: 30px;
}
mat-grid-list {
  width:200px;
}

Answer (score 1):

If your `mat-grid-list` has width = 0px instead of filling the width of the page like it's supposed to, **make sure that your `mat-grid-list` is not inside an element with `display: flex;`**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` value on the `width` property in order to impose the `width` that you want.

For example, add a class into your first `mat-grid-tile` that has the value `30%`:

```
.firstCol {
    width: 30% !important;
}
```

Then add this class to your first `mat-grid-tile` *tag*, which will result in overriding any `width` instruction like (`calc`) imposed by *material lib*.

For me this is old way, but still gold !

Answer (score -1):

@Venetian Village.. you can devide the width of browser with the row class of  CSS. Here `height :100vh` is taking complete the browser window height or if you want use parent's div use `height: 100%`.

```
 <mat-grid-list class="row" cols="2" [cols]="breakpoint" (window:resize)="onResize($event)" style="height:100vh">
       <mat-grid-tile class="col col-lg-4 col-sm-4">

       </mat-grid-tile>
       <mat-grid-tile class="col col-lg-8 col-sm-8">

       </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```