# To set different width for mat-grid-tile in mat-grid-list component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `<mat-grid-list>` in my project as shown in below code

**HTML**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="240px"  (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
     <mat-grid-tile>
           1
     </mat-grid-tile>
     <mat-grid-tile>
           2
     </mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-list>
```

**TS**

```
 import {Component, OnInit, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

 export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
     public ngVersion: string = VERSION.full;
     public matVersion: string = '5.1.0'; 
     public breakpoint: number; 

     ngOnInit() {
       this.breakpoint = (window.innerWidth <= 600) ? 1 : 2;
     }

     onResize(event) {
       this.breakpoint = (event.target.innerWidth <= 600) ? 1 : 2;
    }

  }
```

How can i set first `<mat-grid-tile>` width to **40%** and second  `<mat-grid-tile>` width to **60%**.Tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874045/how-to-set-width-of-mat-grid-tile/51874520) too, still no result.
Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid-q3pvwd?file=app/demo/demo.component.html) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjp21p)

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">


<mat-grid-tile [class.fullWidth]="breakpoint == 1" class="g1">
    Grid 1
</mat-grid-tile>

<mat-grid-tile [class.fullWidth]="breakpoint == 1" class="g2">
    Grid 2
</mat-grid-tile>
```

css:

```
.g1{
  width: 40% !important ;
  background-color: red;
}
.g2{
  width:60% !important;
  background-color: blue;

}

.fullWidth{
  width: 50% !important ;
}
```

TS:

```
breakpoint: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpoint = (window.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 3;
  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.breakpoint = (event.target.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 3;
  }
```

Comment: I need 2nd <mat-gri-tile> has to come below on resizing.

Comment: Please set the width in this stackblitz link, `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid-q3pvwd?file=app/demo/demo.component.html`

Comment: Okay please carry on.

Comment: You can change CSS as you want conditionally let me ping back if any problem?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,How can i control the height of the `<mat-gri-tile>` according to the content inside, suppose content is less in 1st tile and more in 2nd tile.It should align properly in small devices. Is it possible?

Comment: Using rowHeight property or you can also apply height conditionally like [class.newHeight] where newHeight is updated class

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can we apply rowHeight for a single `<mat-gri-tile>`?, if not can i control `rowHeight ` in media queries?

Comment: you can give height to g1 and g2 class

Comment: I tried giving height to g1 and g2 classes, no changes mean it's taking larger height butunable to take smaller heights.

Comment: Try like this:  height: 100px !important ;

Comment: i tried by giving `!important`, It is taking height more the `100px` but not lesser than `100px` .

Comment: I resolved it using media queries, Thank for your answers.